# How can I get rid of ad_id warning in my app logs?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I have an app that uses firebase-messaging, but do not use ads. There are lots of threads about submitting to Play console problems regarding ad_id and Firebase.

However, I filled in the form and I can release our app fine, but I get a warning log whenever my app launches:

> Package X failed Ad Id permission check. Apps that target Android SDK 33 or higher should declare com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID in the app manifest to access Ad Id.

So, I have tried to get rid of this by adding this to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
```

I also have added:

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

,as per Google documentation. Nothing works, I still get the warning in my logs. Again, it doesn't seem to affect the app, and I can submit.

I would like to get rid of the log though, anybody have any ideas? I don't want to add the permission since my app doesn't use ads at all.

Comment: The warning log you're seeing is related to the Ad ID permission check, and it's asking you to declare the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the app manifest. While you've attempted to remove it using the tools:node="remove" attribute,